Linter check for reference removal in auto type
I wanted to know if there is any compiler option or clang-tidy checks for this situation:
#include<iostream>
#include <ostream>

int glob = 12;

int& test(int d){
    std::cout << &glob << std::endl;
    return glob;
}


int main() {

    auto a = test(10);
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

If I suddenly forget to put the & after the auto, I will see different addresses in the output, and it is expected, but is there any compiler flag or clang-tidy flag that warns me about it?

How do you check for something perfectly safe and legal? You might as well ask the linter to check if you ever mistyped + as -.

@PasserBy A lot of compiler warnings are about things that are perfectly safe and legal, and yet they are checked for. E.g., warning about assignment in if condition.

@Yksisarvinen I did not express myself well. An assignment in a if is unlikely to be correct. There's no such distinction here. What I want to say shouldn't be called "safe", but a better word escapes me.

@PasserBy if ((count = readByte(devAddr, regAddr, &b, timeout)) != 0), this code is correct but it results in a linter warning "an assignment within an 'if' condition is bug-prone: C/C++: bugprone-assignment-in-if-condition", I know that going from int& to int is just a copy and is safe, but I just asked to see if there is anything to tell me that you are creating new instance of your object and you probably didn't mean to.

I'm not aware of an existing warning or check that does this, but one
can use
clang-query
to check for the pattern of declaring a variable using type auto
(which is distinct from auto&) and initializing it with a call to a
function that returns a reference.
The following shell script invokes clang-query with such a
match expression:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

# In the following, the comments are seen and ignored by clang-query
# (not the shell).  But beware that clang-query has odd rules for where
# comments can go, and poor error reporting if the rules are violated.
query='m

  varDecl(                         # Report any variable declaration
    hasType(                       # whose declared type
      autoType()                   # is `auto`,
    ),
    hasInitializer(                # and that has an initializer
      implicitCastExpr(            # that is an implicit conversion
        hasSourceExpression(       # from
          callExpr(                # a function call expression
            callee(                # where the callee
              functionDecl(        # is a directly named function
                returns(           # whose return type
                  referenceType()  # is a reference.
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ).bind("decl")

'

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 filename.cc -- <compile options like -I, etc.>"
  exit 2
fi

# Run the query.  Setting 'bind-root' to false means clang-query will
# not also print a redundant "root" binding.
clang-query \
  -c="set bind-root false" \
  -c="$query" \
  "$@"

# EOF

On the following input:
// test.cc
// Cases for `auto` declaring non-ref initialized from ref.

int &getref();

int getnonref();

void g(int &refparam)
{
  // ref -> ref
  auto &r2r = getref();       // not reported: no conversion

  // ref -> nonref
  auto r2nr = getref();       // reported

  // nonref -> nonref
  auto nr2nr = getnonref();   // not reported: no conversion

  // nonref -> ref: Syntax error.
  //auto &nr2r = getnonref();

  auto rp2nr = refparam;      // not reported: not a call
}

// EOF

it produces the output:
$ ./cmd.sh test.cc --

Match #1:

$PWD/test.cc:14:3: note: "decl" binds here
  auto r2nr = getref();       // reported
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.

In the match expression, I restrict reporting to initializers that are
function calls.  However, depending on what you're after, you might want
to delete the entire hasSourceExpression matcher (so
implicitCastExpr is just followed by ()), thus reporting any auto
declaration initialized using an implicit conversion, since arguably any
such case is "surprising" and perhaps unintended.
I haven't done any large-scale testing or tuning of this matcher, so it
might need further adjustment for use in production.
The procedure for integrating clang-query into a build or test
workflow is basically the same as doing so for clang-tidy, assuming
the latter is done by direct invocation.

The answer is no, you shouldn't do it. Even if you can create custom linter rules for this, the answer is still no. The reason is that whatever linter rules you create for this will invariably have lots of false positives.
For example, in the statement a = b = c;, the return value of the sub-expression of b = c is a non-const reference to b, whose value is then assigned to a. This is the common case. Your example where this isn't the intention is the rare case. When other people reading your code, they are much more likely to believe that auto a = test(1); is the correct form than the one with references, especially when the return value is just an integer. If you want something goes against the grain this much, you need to try much harder than a linter rule.
What you can do is one of the following:
A. Wrap the object you do not want to copy in a struct and delete its copy constructor.
B. Pass around a pointer instead of a reference so memory operations are more obvious.
